# ava support for snapshot property matchers

Tags: ava

Does ava support snapshot property matchers?

I am using ava snapshots to test an API endpoint that returns a JSON object. The response contains some properties that are unique to the request (e.g. timestamp, request id).

I know that Jest allows to use [property matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#property-matchers) so a property can match to any value. I wonder if ava supports this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. Your best bet is to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to remove the changing values before you snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.